# Is there a simple way to read an awk variable silently and allowing a single character?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to write a shell script, which would in some cases ask the user whether they want to delete some file. In this case, a question would pop up: "Do you want to delete said file? [y/N]"

However, this would be called while processing a file line by line, in an awk statement.

Now, the closest I could get is the following code inside the awk:

```
awk 'some other code
     system("read -s -n1 ans && echo $ans | cat > inputf");
     getline del < "inputf";
     if (del=="y") system("echo Deleted Successfully!");
   '
```

This is one weird way of trying to solve it, however, it still doesn't work. Even though the "inputf" file is overwritten in every iteration, the getline command always takes the not-modified, original version of it. Any explanation to this? Or a suggestion of an easier way of doing this? Note: I'd like it to read silently, and a single character.

Comment: I suggest to use a bash script for this.

Answer (score 2):

One approach that makes use of `/dev/stdin`:

```
awk '

function get_response(str) {

    printf "%s ", str                       # leave cursor/prompt at end of output
    getline response < "/dev/stdin";        # read from stdin
    print ""                                # terminate the output line
    return response
}

BEGIN { del = get_response("Do you want to delete said file? [y/N]")
        print "response = ",del
      }
'
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
Do you want to delete said file? [y/N] y

response =  y

-------------

Do you want to delete said file? [y/N] N

response =  N
```

Comment: In case the user supplies a multi-char response, you may want to add `del=substr(del,1,1)` . Good luck to all.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you are prompting for input via `/dev/stdin` in `awk` you are missing the speed benefit provided by `awk`. While doable, and it may be perfectly fine for your circumstance, it's not something generally done. That's what shell scripting is for.